# React-Sigma Graph not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graph

I'm using this library: https://github.com/dunnock/react-sigma to display a simple graph using the react web Framework, I have a dashboard page with some components:

-Visits
-Crowd
-Pieces

In the Crowd component I want to display a simple graph (like the example one):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

    import {Sigma, RandomizeNodePositions, RelativeSize} from 'react-sigma';
    
    
    /**
     * Class to display to a user the dashboard of his/her museum
     * @author Giulio Serra
     */
    export default class Crowd extends Component {
        
        render(){
            let myGraph = {nodes:[{id:"n1", label:"Alice"}, {id:"n2", label:"Rabbit"}], edges:[{id:"e1",source:"n1",target:"n2",label:"SEES"}]};
            return <div><Sigma graph={myGraph} settings={{drawEdges: true, clone: false}}>
            <RelativeSize initialSize={15}/>
            <RandomizeNodePositions/>
          </Sigma></div>
        }
    }
```

But the page it's just blank:

[image]

Am I missing something? Thanks